# Error is : Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Tags: magento-2.1, error, exception

I am keep getting this error with my code although I only followed their instructions.

```
<?php 

namespace Training\Test\App;

class FrontController extends \Magento\Framework\App\FrontController

{

protected $routerList;

protected $response;

protected $logger;

public function __construct(

    \Magento\Framework\App\RouterList $routerList,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)

{

    $this->routerList = $routerList;
    $this->response = $response;
    $this->logger = $logger;
}


public function dispatch(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
{
    foreach($this->routerList as $router)
    {
        $this->logger->addDebug(get_class($router));
    }
    return parent::dispatch($request);
}


}
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem appeared because you didn't execute parent constructor. Correct version of your code:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\RouterList $routerList,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)

{

    $this->routerList = $routerList;
    $this->response = $response;
    $this->logger = $logger;

    parent::__construct($routerList, $response);
}
```